# How to make a dynamic list of elements appear horizontally up to each 6 index and then vertically in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a dynamic list which will be increased every 10 seconds and I want this list to be displayed in flutter UI in such a way that the first 6 numbers should display on the first line and the next 6 numbers should display on the next line and so on.

Currently, the code I made just displays a list in a horizontally scrollable view.

```
Widget horizontalList1 = new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
        height: 40.0,
        child: new ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: calledNumersArray(),
        )
    );
```

[image: Image for referece]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `GridView` and limit its `CrossAxisCount`

```
Widget horizontalList1 = new Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
    height: 40.0,
    child: GridView.count(
      count: calledNumbersArraay().length
      crossAxisCount: 6,
      children: calledNumersArray(),
    )
);
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html

Comment: Thanks. This snippet worked for me with minor tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding elements dynamically, I suggest you use a `builder` constructor to avoid performance issues. I think [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) can help you here. However, you'd need to refactor your code so that your number widgets are generated in the `itemBuilder` function.

Like so:

```
 final calledNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]; // generate the numbers somehow
 Widget horizontalList1 = Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: calledNumbers.length,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 8,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { // create the widgets here
            final calledNumber = calledNumbers[index];
            return Container(
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                key: ValueKey(index), // make sure to add a key
                child: Center(child: Text(calledNumber.toString())),
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red));
          },
));
```

The result:

[image: GridView result]